Installing Ubuntu hangs on cursor
I tried searching around to find a post that covered the installation of Ubuntu hanging after selecting to try or install. I also searched the forum for my specific model of device and found some people having trouble depending on the model number but none listing mine specifically. Some people also had success but with great effort. I'm hoping someone here is familiar with installing Ubuntu on a Samsung Galaxy Book 2 (SM-W737P). It meets the minimum requirements listed on the Ubuntu install page. It has 4GB of RAM, 128GB hard drive SDXC, and Qualcomm Snapdragon 850 which is ARM64 architecture with eight cores.
I understand that Snapdragon has very little support for Linux of any kind, but I'm not sure if someone has had any weird luck because right now it runs terrible on Windows 10 and 11 and is essentially a paperweight.
What I've tried (Some challenges I've overcome):

Could not see drive on boot list to change priority. The solution to this was formatting the USB to NTFS instead of the FAT format it was in.
I disabled fast boot in the power options in windows 11.
Disabled secure boot and dealt with bit locker recovery codes
I wasn't able to get to the grub but when I try to boot to the drive it goes to a blank screen and after a few seconds boots back into windows. After some trouble shooting I discovered I was using the AMD 64 version of Ubuntu 24.04 so I downloaded and created a new boot drive for the ARM 64 version 22.04.4 with NTFS formatting.
I was still getting a hanging cursor after selecting try or install so I tried to edit the boot parameters which were (look below) and that's all there was and I was looking for a reference to quiet splash to replace with nomodeset but there wasn't that as you can see but there was quiet so I replaced that with nomodeset and I got "Booting a command list", "EFI stub: Booting Linux kernel...", "EFI stub: Using DTB from configuration table", and "EFI stub: Exiting boot services...". It then exits the boot drive and restarts just to return back to the try or install grub menu.

I'm at a loss for what to do next and I feel as though I've exhausted my own knowledge and don't have the knowledge to know how to continue researching this issue.
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd

